# Passing value of checked checkboxes via AJAX to Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote the below function to get value of checked checkboxes ,so that I can send the value to Java class using AJAX, the name of variable I have used in code is checkID.

```
 function getParam()
    {
        alert ($("#paramNameVal").val());
        //  $paramName=$('#paramName');
       // alert("Hi");

        var elements = $("[name^='Day']");
         var units = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            //  alert("for");
                var element = $(elements[i]);
                alert(element);
                if (element.is(":checked")){
                    units.push(element.val());
                }
            }

        var stringy = JSON.stringify(units);
        //alert(stringy);
        var interval=document.getElementById('time').value;
        $("#showParam1").html("");
        $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "dojo_Getgrid.action",  
              data:{Interval:interval ,Userlist : $("#paramNameVal").val(),checkID : stringy },
              // data: { ,},
              //data:$("#paramName").val(), 
              success: function( response ) {
                    console.log( response );
                    alert(response);
                    $("#showParam1").html(response);
                   // document.getElementById("showParam").style.display='block';
                  }          
              });
    }
```

but inside java class, I just get ["true" ,"true"] in case I select two checkboxes instead of actual value of checkbox.

Below are the checkboxes

```
<s:form name="parameterGrid" theme="simple" >
         <fieldset > 
         <table style=" margin: 0px;" border="0"
                    class="table-form">

                <tr >
                        <td align="justify"><s:label key="Everyday"></s:label></td>
                        <td align="justify"><s:checkbox name="All" id="All" theme="simple" onclick="check();"></s:checkbox></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>        
                        <td ><s:label key="Sunday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[1]" id="D1" fieldValue="Sunday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td ><s:label key="Monday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[2]"  id="D2" fieldValue="Monday"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td><s:label key="Tuesday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[3]"  id="D3" fieldValue="Tuesday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td><s:label key="Wednesday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[4]"  id="D4" fieldValue="Wednesday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td><s:label key="Thursday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[5]"  id="D5" fieldValue="Thursday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td><s:label key="Friday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[6]"  id="D6" fieldValue="Friday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                        <td><s:label key="Saturday"></s:label></td>
                        <td ><s:checkbox name="Day[7]"  id="D7" fieldValue="Saturday"  theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>

                        <%-- <s:hidden name="day1" id="day1" value="%{day1}" /> --%>
                    </tr>

                    </table>
```

Comment: Because you're just pushing the `val()` of checked checkboxes into units. If you want to receive separate keys on in your java class, you should add separate parameters

Comment: which is the checkboxes values?

Comment: I have added the checkboxes above

Answer (score 0):

I never used Struts form but generally you can get element attribute value by jQuery.
check this out for detail parameters!!
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/checkbox.html

instead of
units.push(element.val());
try
units.push(element.attr('fieldValue'));

hope it will work!!

Answer (score 0):

First set the values for your checkboxes, for example

```
<input class="Day1" type="checkbox" value="one">
<input class="Day2" type="checkbox" value="two">
<input class="Day3" type="checkbox" value="three">
```

If you want to access the values

```
var checkedValues = $("[name^='Day']:checked").map(function(){
             return $(this).val();
     }).get();
```